# Deserializing Array of arrays from json

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am trying to deserialize an array of array of Strings using `ObjectMapper`. The input has the following structure: `[["key", "value"], ["Car", "1"], ["SUV", "1.1"]]`

I have tried to de-serialize this by using the following method:

```
JavaType itemType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Array.class);
List<T> mutableList = objectMapper.readValue(json.or("[]"), itemType);
```

However, the compiler complains of raw use of parameterized class.
Could someone please explain how to serialize such an input ?

Comment: Are you using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Jackson. The answer by Deadpool solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you have is an Array with Array of string object and error message indicates to specify the exact type, so I would suggest to use [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) with exact type

```
List<List<String>> listCar = objectMapper.readValue(json.or("[]"), new TypeReference<List<List<String>>>(){});
```

Comment: Much appreciated ! - Thanks